# What does backtick mean in LISP?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, backticks

I have this macro, which rewrites define. If I remove the " ` " backtick it won't work. What is the explanation?

```
(defmacro define ((name &rest r) body) 
  `(defun ,name ,r ,body))
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A single quote followed by the written representation of a value
will produce that value:

Example:
    '(1 x "foo")
will produce a value that prints as `(1 x "foo")`.

Suppose now that I don't want a literal symbol `x` in the list.
I have a variable `x` in my program, and I want to insert
the value to which `x` is bound.

To mark that I want the value of `x` rather than the symbol `x`,
I insert a comma before `x`:

```
'(1 ,x "foo")
```

It won't work as-is though - I now get a value that has a literal comma as well as a symbol `x`. The problem is that `quote` does not know about the comma convention.

Backtick or `backquote` knows about the comma-convention, so that will give the correct result:

```
> `(1 ,x "foo")
(1 3 "foo")          ; if the value of x is 3
```

Read more here: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm

Comment: Great, I got it, thanks. One more thing. What does that & operator before rest do? (&rest)

Comment: The `&rest` allows you to define functions that have a variable amount of arguments. Say you want to define a plus function where both (plus 2 3) and (plus 2 3 4) works. This page has a nice explanation: http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/functions.html

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this feature is called **quasiquoting** or **quasi-quoting**.

Answer (score 7):

The backtick/backquote disables evaluation for every subexpression not preceded by a comma for the list that follows the operator.

From the common lisp cookbook, [explanation and a few examples](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/macros.html#LtohTOCentry-2).