# Add a decorator function to org-capture-template

Tags: elisp, org-mode

I wrote a org-capture-templates which add entries to appropriate headings as:

> ** Plan
> ** Writing

The org-capture-templates as:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("p" "Plan" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/Master/todo.today.org"
                        (my-org-goto-last-headline "\\*\\* Plan"))
         "* TODO %i%?")
        ("w" "Writing" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/Master/todo.today.org"
                        (my-org-goto-last-headline "\\*\\* Writing"))
         "* %i%? \n%T")))
```

`my-org-goto-last-headline` was defined as a decorator:

```
(defun my-org-goto-last-headline (heading)
  (defun nested ()
    "Move point to the last headline in file matching \"** Headline\"."
    (end-of-buffer)
    (re-search-backward heading))
  `nested)
```

Additionally, I set `lexical-binding: t`

Unfortunately, it report errors like:

```
org-capture-set-target-location: Invalid function: (my-org-goto-last-headline "\\*\\* Plan")
```

How could I apply a decorator in such a org-capture-template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function format should be `(file+function "filename" function-finding-location)`.

You are not providing a function itself. You are giving it a list `(function argument)`. Since it is not being executed you have that error.

You could write it in backquote and evaluate the function that returns the function object.

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      `(("p" "Plan" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/Master/todo.today.org"
                        ,(my-org-goto-last-headline "\\*\\* Plan"))
         "* TODO %i%?")
        ("w" "Writing" entry
         (file+function "~/Documents/OrgMode/ORG/Master/todo.today.org"
                        ,(my-org-goto-last-headline "\\*\\* Writing"))
         "* %i%? \n%T")))
```

You will also need to quote the return `nested` in my-org- function.

Comment: Is it backquote ` or  comma , ?

Comment: @AbstProcDo: yes

Comment: @rajashekar what do you mean by "yes"? which one is it: comma or backtick?

Comment: @AbstProcDo could you, please, accept the answer if it satisfies you?

Comment: @AbstProcDo: comma goes before an expression within a backquoted expression. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30150186/what-does-backtick-mean-in-lisp