# Common lisp: calling a class method in a separate thread

Tags: multithreading, lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to build a common lisp implementation of the channel construct of Golang for a personal project (also to learn lisp). So far I've  implemented the channels as objects of a class, containing a queue, a lock and a condition variable to signal listening functions that a new message has been added to the queue.  I'm using bordeaux threads to create threads, locks, condition variables and join the executions (from the [lisp cookbook](https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/process.html#joining-on-a-thread-destroying-a-thread-example)).

This is the channel class and the `recive` function:

```lisp
(defclass channel ()
  ((messages :initform '()
             :accessor messages
             :documentation "Messages in the channel")
   (lock :initform (bt:make-lock)
         :accessor lock
         :documentation
         "Lock to push/pop messages in the channel")
   (cv :initarg :cv
       :initform (bt:make-condition-variable)
       :accessor cv
       :documentation
       "Condtional variable to notify the channel of a new message")))


(defmethod recive-loop ((self channel))
  (with-slots (lock cv messages) self
    (let ((to-ret nil))
    (loop
     (bt:with-lock-held (lock)
       (if (not (null messages))
           (setf to-ret (car (pop messages)))
           (bt:condition-wait cv lock))
       (if to-ret (return to-ret)))))))

(defmethod recive ((self channel))
  (with-slots (name thread) self
    (let ((thread
            (bt:make-thread #'(lambda() (recive-loop self))
                            :name name)))
      (bt:join-thread thread))))

(defmacro gorun (f &rest args)
  (flet ((fn () (apply f args)))
    (bt:make-thread #'fn
            :initial-bindings (list args)
            :name "gorun worker")))
```

`gorun` should be the equivalent of `go routine()` for go (without the light threading). To test the setup I've built a printer function over a channel

```lisp
(defvar printch (channel))

(defun printover (ch)
  (let ((x (recive ch)))
    (format t "Recived variable x: ~d~%" x)))
```

but when I run

```lisp
(gorun printover printch)
```

The interpreter (using `sbcl`, but with `clisp` the same happens) gives back an error:

```
There is no applicable method for the generic function
  #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::RECIVE (1)>
when called with arguments
  (PRINTCH).
   [Condition of type SB-PCL::NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD-ERROR]
See also:
  Common Lisp Hyperspec, 7.6.6 [:section]

Restarts:
 0: [RETRY] Retry calling the generic function.
 1: [ABORT] abort thread (#<THREAD "gorun worker" RUNNING {100293E9F3}>)

Backtrace:
  0: ((:METHOD NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD (T)) #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::RECIVE (1)> PRINTCH) [fast-method]
      Locals:
        SB-PCL::ARGS = (PRINTCH)
        GENERIC-FUNCTION = #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::RECIVE (1)>
  1: (SB-PCL::CALL-NO-APPLICABLE-METHOD #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::RECIVE (1)> (PRINTCH))
      Locals:
        ARGS = (PRINTCH)
        GF = #<STANDARD-GENERIC-FUNCTION COMMON-LISP-USER::RECIVE (1)>
  2: (PRINTOVER PRINTCH)
      Locals:
        CH = PRINTCH
  3: ((LAMBDA NIL :IN BORDEAUX-THREADS::BINDING-DEFAULT-SPECIALS))
      [No Locals]
```

I'm confused, since the method to run over the channel `printch` should be the one I've defined.

Trying to call a class method inside of a new thread, but got `no applicable method`

Comment: Is there a reason for GORUN being a macro? Why does the macro GORUN doesn't generate any code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A macros is supposed to return code to run in place of the original call. Your macro is creating the thread at expansion time.

If you're not using backtick in a macro definition, there's usually something wrong with it. You should figure out what the code would look like without the macro, then define a macro that returns code with that same structure in a backticked list, replacing the places that need to vary with the parameters, using comma to expand them.

```
(defmacro gorun (f &rest args)
  `(bt:make-thread (function ,f)
        :initial-bindings (list ,@args)
        :name "gorun worker"))
```

In the above, you need to substitute the function name into a `(function ...)` expression, and the `args` list as the `:initial-bindings` argument.

Comment: You're answering a newbie. Maybe you could spend a few words to explain the [_backquote expression_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30150276/801894) that you used in your version of the macro.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've added some details, although teaching macro writing is more than I can do in a couple of paragraphs. I remember how long it took me to "get it" when I was learning lisp.

Comment: Thanks a lot! now the error is in another part of the code, so this is the correct answer. Also I'm still familiarizing with writing macros, your suggestions were really useful!

Comment: My Lisp days are waaaay behind me, but yeah, I remember coming to terms with the power of macros. As I recall, I spent a fair amount of time playing around in the REPL; evaluating backquote expressions, trying out macros after changing `defmacro` to `defun` so I could see what they expanded into, trying to write non-backquote expressions that would cons up the same result as a backquote expression, etc. One project I worked on, somebody profiled it, found out that about a third of all the compiled code came from one expansion of one macro that I wrote. Oops! Be careful with them things!

Comment: @SolomonSlow the `MACROEXPAND` function is useful, instead of converting to `DEFUN`.

Answer (score 1):

In multi-threaded environments it is often the case that special variables are thread-local. The global binding is visible from all threads, but if you bind one locally its value will not automatically be transferred to a thread created in that context. It has to be done explicitly, and I wrote a pair of macros recently just for that.

The first one captures bindings into lexically-scoped variables; the other bind the original variables back to the values captured in a different context.

I am using an intermediate data structure in the code to store bindings:

```
(defstruct bindings data)
```

The first macro is `with-captured-bindings`:

```
(defmacro with-captured-bindings ((&rest symbols) as name &body body)
  (assert (eq as :as))
  (loop for s in (alexandria:flatten
                  (sublis
                   '((:stdio *standard-output* *error-output* *standard-input*)
                     (:path *default-pathname-defaults*))
                   symbols))
        for g = (gensym)
        collect (list g s) into capture
        collect (list s g) into rebind
        finally
           (return
             `(let ,capture
                ,@(subst (make-bindings :data rebind)
                         name
                         body)))))
```

The `capture` variable holds a list of bindings to initialize the lexically-scoped variables. The `rebind` variables is a list of bindings to set back special variables to their values in another thread.

I inject with `subst` an instance of the `bindings` struct in the code. It helps to have a dedicated data structure, but the crude search-and-replace approach means the symbols `name` will not be usable as a function, local macro, etc. in `body`. I don't think it is too much of a problem.

Also, I define aliases like `:stdio` and `:path` for commonly used variables.

The second macro is `with-bindings`:

```
(defmacro with-bindings (bindings &body body)
  (check-type bindings bindings)
  `(let ,(bindings-data bindings)
     ,@body))
```

This replaces the intermediate struct with the proper code. The final code does not have this struct anymore and can be processed as usual.

For example:

```
(defvar *my-var* "hello")

(with-captured-bindings (:stdio :path *my-var*) :as <bindings>
  (sb-thread:make-thread 
   (lambda ()
     (with-bindings <bindings>
       (print *var*)))))
```

A first application of macroexpand gives:

```
(LET ((#:G3882 *STANDARD-OUTPUT*)
      (#:G3883 *ERROR-OUTPUT*)
      (#:G3884 *STANDARD-INPUT*)
      (#:G3885 *DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS*)
      (#:G3886 *MY-VAR*))
  (SB-THREAD:MAKE-THREAD
   (LAMBDA ()
     (WITH-BINDINGS #S(BINDINGS
                       :DATA ((*STANDARD-OUTPUT* #:G3882)
                              (*ERROR-OUTPUT* #:G3883)
                              (*STANDARD-INPUT* #:G3884)
                              (*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS* #:G3885)
                              (*MY-VAR* #:G3886)))
       (PRINT *MY-VAR*)))))
```

Notice that there is `#S(BINDINGS ...)` object in the tree.

The full expansion is:

```
(LET ((#:G3887 *STANDARD-OUTPUT*)
      (#:G3888 *ERROR-OUTPUT*)
      (#:G3889 *STANDARD-INPUT*)
      (#:G3890 *DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS*)
      (#:G3891 *MY-VAR*))
  (SB-THREAD:MAKE-THREAD
   (LAMBDA ()
     (LET ((*STANDARD-OUTPUT* #:G3887)
           (*ERROR-OUTPUT* #:G3888)
           (*STANDARD-INPUT* #:G3889)
           (*DEFAULT-PATHNAME-DEFAULTS* #:G3890)
           (*MY-VAR* #:G3891))
       (PRINT *MY-VAR*)))))
```

Comment: thank you a lot! This is very useful since the next error that came out was about binding variables in the thread, so this was very useful